# angularJs: how can I update my selectbox dom content after deleting item in the ng-repeat value?

Tags: angularjs, dom, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing some problem with dom in my angular page.
Here is my code :

```
$scope.tab2 = [
            {value:"value1"},
            {value:"value2"},
            {value:"value3"},
            {value:"value4"}
        ] ;
```

I fill a selectbox with that variable:

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectedInTab2" style="height:300px; width:300px;">
    <option ng-repeat="elt in tab2"  value="{{elt.value}}" > {{elt.value}} </option>
</select>
```

I have a button that remove element from this variable like this
$scope.tab2.splice(selectedObjIndex, 1);

The problem is that, after I remove element from the tab2, I see an empty row in my selectbox. And on chrome dev tool I see that :

```
<select multiple="" ng-model="selectedInTab2" style="height:300px; width:300px;">
    <option value="? string:3173 ?"></option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: value in tab2 -->
    <option ng-repeat="value in tab2" value="1356"> 1356 </option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: value in tab2 -->
    <option ng-repeat="value in tab2" value="2248"> 2248 </option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: value in tab2 -->
    <option ng-repeat="value in tab2" value="2434"> 2434 </option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: value in tab2 -->
</select>
```

So, as you can see, the empty row represent , that is no more in tab2 variable.

How can I do to update also DOM of this selectbox when I process the removeElement function, with angularJs ? I know i can be possible with jQuery.

Comment: Where is the code where you are removing the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: after deletion you need initiate new `selected` value, for example by updating `selectedInTab2`.   Angular sets `value="? string:3173 ?"` as default for non-selected value.

So try this:  Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/59/)**</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem"
            ng-options="selectedItem as selectedItem.value  for selectedItem in tab2"
    ></select>
     <p>
        <button ng-click="remove(tab2.indexOf(selectedItem))" >remove</button>
      </p>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.tab2 = [
            {value:"value1"},
            {value:"value2"},
            {value:"value3"},
            {value:"value4"}
        ] ;

      $scope.selectedItem = $scope.tab2[0];
    $scope.remove = function(selectedObjIndex){

        console.log(selectedObjIndex);

    $scope.tab2.splice(selectedObjIndex, 1);
        $scope.selectedItem = $scope.tab2[0];
    };  

}
```